# How to dump pandas dataframe as json

Tags: json, pandas

While dumping a dataframe to json getting escape characters along with double qoutes

```
Expected Output : 
"[{"a":"1","b":"5"},
{"a":"2","b":"6"},
{"a":"3","b":"7"},
{"a":"4","b":"8"}]"
Result : 
"[{\"a\":\"1\",\"b\":\"5\"},
 {\"a\":\"2\",\"b\":\"6\"},
 {\"a\":\"3\",\"b\":\"7\"},
 {\"a\":\"4\",\"b\":\"8\"}]" 
 AB1 = AB.to_json(orient='records',encoding='utf-8')
 return json.dumps(AB1)
```

Comment: `AB1` is your JSON. `json.dumps(AB1)` is jsonifying a JSON string, and that ends up just escaping it.

Comment: @ernest_k - exactly, can you create answer or find dupe if exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the to_json part. Depending on what your input is, just use dump or dumps.